# Recurring nightmare-Pia's Revolution

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Recurring nightmare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRecurring%20nightmare%5d) and a [Pia's Revolution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPia%27s%5d%2b%5bRevolution%5d) in play, can I sacrifice an artifact creature and then return it to my hand along with the Recurring Nightmare and an additional creature card from my graveyard?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to include some detail about what part of the interaction you are unclear about. Is there a reason you think that it might not work like you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

That's more or less right, though things happen in a specific order.

First you activate the ability on Recurring Nightmare. To do this, must choose the target creature that you wish to return to the battlefield. Note that the artifact creature you plan to sacrifice is not in the graveyard at this time, so it is not a legal target.

You pay the cost of sacrificing a creature (choosing an artifact creature) and returning Recurring Nightmare to your hand. This places the ability on the stack.

Then the triggered ability on Pia's Revolution triggers because a non-token artifact was put into your graveyard from the battlefield. At this time you must choose a target opponent, and then the Pia's Revolution's ability goes on the stack.

Assuming both players choose to pass priority now, the Pia's Revolution ability will resolve. The target opponent chooses whether to take 3 damage or allow you to return your artifact creature to your hand. Whichever they choose will happen.

Then, assuming both players choose to pass priority again, the Recurring Nightmare's ability will resolve, which will allow you to return a creature card from your graveyard to the battlefield.

The end result will be 1 of 2 things, depending on your opponent's choice:

1. You have Recurring Nightmare in your hand, the artifact creature you chose to sacrifice in your hand, and another creature that was in your graveyard is now on the battlefield.
2. You have Recurring Nightmare in your hand, and another creature that was in your graveyard is now on the battlefield. The artifact creature you chose to sacrifice is still in the graveyard, but your opponent takes 3 damage.

Comment: I was confused because I wasn't sure if I was using multiple effects when sacrificing the artifact creature.  I'm glad you cleared that up for me. Thanks!